# Changing multiple dataframe columns datatype using a list of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv that I am puling into a dataframe(df) that has a large number of columns.  Below is a cut down version of the table:

```
Quarter  Response   Exception   Approved   On Hold
   2017         5         4           4          7
2017 Q1         3         5           2          7
2017 Q1         2         6           8          9
2017 Q2         8         4           5          3
2017 Q2         3         8           8          2
2017 Q2         3         6           8          6
```

The data type of all columns is currently object.
Quarter   object
Response  object
Exception object
Approved  object
On Hold   object

I would like to change the datatype of a number of columns (not all) to float.  Is it possible to create a list of columns that I'd like to covert and use this to change the data types of those specific columns? For example the list of columns to convert might be:

```
Columns = ['Response', 'Exception', 'Approved','On Hold']

df[Columns].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce')

Quarter   object
Response   float
Exception  float
Approved   float
On Hold    float
```

I've tried running the above but not all of the requested columns have their data type changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The df.apply() method doesn't change the original dataframe and so you need something like:

```
df[Columns] = df[Columns].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```